# Ошибка DataGridView при попытке добавления фото в запись

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Имеется БД с таблицей:

[image: таблица]

И форма с элементом dataGridView, который привязан к этой таблице:

[image: форма]

В таблице имеются записи, у которых поле Photo пусто. Программа запускается и всё хорошо отображается.
Добавляю в таблицу с помощью запроса запись, в которой содержится фотография:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Nationality ([Title], [Language], [Culture], [Religion], [Photo])
VALUES ('title', 'language', 'culture', 'religion', 'E:\picture.jpg')
```

После этого программа запускается и тут же выдаёт ошибку:

[image: ошибка]

При попытке выбора любой записи возникает такая же ошибка.

Из-за чего может возникать эта ошибка?

Comment: Что за БД, расскажете? Как данные попадают в DGV? Покажите код заполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема возникает из-за неправильного запроса, файл нужно вставлять по-другому. Вот так получилось, с ним ошибки не возникает:

```
INSERT INTO Nationality (Title, Language, Culture, Religion, Photo)
SELECT 'test', 'lang', 'cult', 'rel', BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk 'E:\picture.jpg', Single_Blob) as picture
```